# How to remove a certain starting symbol and its closing symbol, but not the contents?

Tags: php, regex, string

Consider this string:

```
foo{This is my inner content. Hello}
```

What I want to do with regex is make it so it becomes like this:

```
This is my inner content. Hello
```

Note that I only want to match `foo{` and `}`, when put together and used like that. I don't want, for example, `foo2{` and `}`.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/foo\{([^}]*)\}/', '$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems pretty simple:

```
/foo{(.*?)}/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_match

```
$string = "foo{This is my inner content. Hello}";
preg_match("/\{(.*?)\}/", $string, $match);  
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Is it a standard or something to escape the braces?

Comment: It is for getting the content inside the braces, no need to worry about foo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/foo\{(.*)\}/U', $str, $matches);
```

Then `$matches[1]` will contain the string you're after.